# How to get time stamp value from date/month/year format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Iam trying to check whether the input date value from date picker is greater than the current time. Iam getting the date value in date/month/year format.

I want to check whether the input date is greater than current date. But can't get the time stamp from date/mpnth/year format.

```
  function parseDate(input) {
    if(input!=false){
        var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
        var q=Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); // months are 0-based
        return q;
    }
}

if(new Date().getTime()<Date.parse(parseDate($("#sdate").val()))){
    $("#err_startdate").html("Start date must be leass then current time");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a date string to initialize a new Date object:

```
var d = new Date('12/10/2011');
d.getTime(); // 1323428400000
```